# jQueryUI sortable list triggers link

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQueryUI (1.9.2) to make two list sortable. Both lists contain various links. Everythings works fine when an element is dragged and dropped from one list into the other.
However when I use

```
receive:function(event, ui) {
  ui.item.empty();
}
```

or

```
receive:function(event, ui) {
  ui.item.html('whatever');
}
```

Then each time a link is dragged and dropped from one list into the other a "click event" is triggered on that link. It's obvious that this shouldn't happen. How do I prevent these click events? Allready tried things like

```
receive:function(event, ui) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  ui.item.empty();
}
```

as well as to register a start function which disables all links. However both didn't work.
So how to disable all link triggers when sorting between lists?